# ExtJS window don't work

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to learn ExtJs and at the outset I have a problem. Do not show the desired window

[window that does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2ffp.jpg)

This is my code

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM8rX.jpg)

Comment: What version of extjs you are using?

Comment: But, with this code it works

Comment: <body>
<script>
function buildWindow(){
var win = new Ext.Window({
  title: 'Accordion Window',
  width: 200,
  height: 150,
  layout: 'accordion',
  border: false,
  layoutConfig: {
    animate: true
  },
  items:[
    {
      xtype: 'panel',
      title: 'Plain Panel',
      html: 'Panel with an xtype specified'
    },
    {
      title: 'Plain Panel 2',
      html: 'Panel with <b>no</b> xtype specified'
    }
  ]
});
win.show();
}
Ext.onReady(buildWindow);
</script>
</body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this code. Its working as expected.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    new Ext.Window({
    title: 'Accordion Window',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    layout: 'accordion',
    border: false,
    layoutConfig : {
        animate : true
    },
    items : [{
        xtype: 'panel',
      title: 'Plain Panel',
      html: 'Plain Panel 1'
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
      title: 'Plain Panel',
      html: 'Plain Panel 2'
    }]

    }).show();
});
```

[Fidle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshkedari/hrsrtvve/)